# SQLite Manager 4 : unable to open database file

Tags: mac, sqlite

I have recently purchased and installed the software [SQLite Manager 4](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/sqlitemanager-4/id604707021?mt=12), now I am creating new SQLite3 database and whenever I try to create new table with 'xyz' name with any number of column, it gives me error stating "unable to open database file".

No other details is given on that part. I also searched for FAQ and other user manual, but did not succeed.

Please help me on this part.

Thank you.

Comment: How did you create the database file?

Comment: On clicking new sqlite database.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is a file-based database engine, and is therefor dependent on appropriate file permissions.

Check that the directory containing the database file is read-write-executable (rwx or octal 7) by the current user, and also check that the database file itself is read- and writeable (rw or octal 6).

Comment: Can you please tell me how to check it? Since I am unable to find any settings.